# Как изменить корневую директорию сайта?

Tags: .htaccess, apache, laravel, httpd

Есть хостинг, на нём стоит cPanel, установил туда `laravel` и `CMS` построенную на этом фреймворке.

Последний штрих, который осталось сделать(судя по мануалу разработчиков) - заменить корневую директорию сайта с `public_html` на `public_html/public`, чтобы корректно работала подгрузка скриптов, стилей и т.д. и т.п.

В самой cPanel не нашел возможности менять корневую директорию сайта, может есть способ сделать это в `.htaccess` или в `httpd.conf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можешь просто прописать путь приложения в httpd.conf

```
DocumentRoot "/path_to_laravel_project/public_html/public"
<Directory "/path_to_laravel_project/public_html/public">
```

Или же в .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public_html/public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Тут есть проблемка, судя по всему на хостинге ограничен доступ к некоторым папкам, не могу найти файл httpd.conf

Comment: А файл .htaccess доступен для записи?

Comment: Доступен, сейчас попробую

Comment: Он редиректит в эту папку, а нужно, чтобы он считал эту папку корневой(причуды `laravel` и этой `CMS`)...

Comment: Так что тут судя по всему только через `httpd.conf` работать

Answer (score 0):

необходимо по SSH из папки проекта создать символическую ссылку

ln -s public/ public_html